# Can I make changes in manage.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am doing a django project where I want my manage.py to run the server automatically(python manage.py runserver command) if its called. I believe that manage.py uses "execute_from_command_line". So is it possible or I have to find some other way to solve my problem.

I want my manage.py to run the server automatically

Comment: if you are talking about the django development server, its already rerun for the changes in the code base.

Comment: actually I am making a .exe file of my project. For that I have to run a command where manage.py is called. So I want if it is possible to make changes in manage.py such that I can runserver just by calling manage.py.